# GraphQL Apollo query with variable 400 error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, apollo

I'm stuck, trying to make query with variable and can't pass variable. What I'm doing wrong? I'm getting Error sending the query 'cinemaDetail' Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

When I manually  write id in query everything is ok, so I think problem is with variable passing.

Its my query:

```
export const CINEMA_DETAIL = gql `
query cinemaDetail($id: String!)  { 
        cinemaDetail(id: $id) {
          id
          slug
          hallNamesss
        }
}
`
```

and vue code:

```
apollo: {
      cinemaDetail: {
        query: CINEMA_DETAIL,
        variables () {
          return {
            id: "Q2luZW1hRGV0YWlsTm9kZTo1"
          }
        },
      }
    },
```

Working version without variable:

```
export const CINEMA_DETAIL = gql `
query  { 
        cinemaDetail(id: "Q2luZW1hRGV0YWlsTm9kZTo1") {
          id
          slug
          hallName
        }
}
`

apollo: {
      cinemaDetail: {
        query: CINEMA_DETAIL
      }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for answer it's not this, I just edited post.

Comment: This looks right, can you add the code snippet for when it does work? (e.g. with hardcoding)

Comment: Ok, I already found solution. I change variables () { return .. } to variables: { .. } and everything is working now. Thanks for help.